# When to use AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

Let's say we have a page written in PHP. This page loads by it self a template with header, body and footer and print this out. Now let's say that in the body of this page we would like to start a loop and load some posts (messages taken from a database).

We also need the page to load new posts every 10 seconds, if any, without refreshing the page (classic AJAX). This ajax call will use JSON and AJAX and micro templates.

Now i'm just wondering:

> Do we really need PHP to load posts the first time the page is loaded? Can't we just start that Ajax call and load posts with Ajax instead? (Notice that the existing ajax call would be kept as it is, since it loads posts starting from the latest loaded (in case of no posts, that would mean all posts).

If you did not understand my question don't hesitate to let me know.

Comment: Similar... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069495/ajax-v-including-data-in-the-html/5069704#5069704

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this situation I think the simpler approach is the let AJAX handle it, if you do let php load the initial messages, you'll have two places in code, that you'll need to maintain to perform identical jobs.

Comment: @Charlie - What do you mean "What about safety?"

Comment: Is PHP-ONLY-method and AJAX-method the same about safety?

Comment: @Charlie: No. I'd recommend reading Ajax Security: http://www.amazon.com/Ajax-Security-Billy-Hoffman/dp/0321491939. Ajax opens up more attack surfaces.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking how you should load the posts the first time the page is accessed. If so: When the page firsts loads, have some PHP that prints out the existing posts. Then, add some JavaScript to update the page with new posts every 10 seconds. This is a matter of preference. You might want there to be no posts when the page first loads, and then use Ajax to get the existing posts once your page has loaded.

**Edit:**

I agree with jondavidjohn that you might be better off using pure Ajax. However, you could always isolate the code that fetches the pages into a separate function. That way, the script that generates the page calls the same function as the script that is called via Ajax.

Answer (score 1):

The drawback with that technique is that it doesn't downgrade gracefully. So people with javascript disabled will not see any posts.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend outputting some data with php - AJAX requires JavaScript which many people don't have activated.

Comment: Actually Javascript is needed. How could sites like Twitter and Facebook works without Javascript?

Comment: @Charlie: Turn off JavaScript, and try visiting those pages. All the interactivity may not work, but the sites function.

Comment: Charlie, they work but statically. If everything would be done by AJAX, people without JS wouldn't see much...

Comment: It's obviously true (as SimpleCoder has said) that some functionality will be lost on certain pages if JS is disabled, but if the initial fetch is strictly HTML generated by a server-side PHP script, then the page's content will still be displayed.  If all of the content is fetched with AJAX, then nothing will be displayed if JS is disabled.  The only way to avoid this is to put the content in noscript tags.

Answer (score 0):

Why not, instead of having the browser poll the server for new posts, have the browser push new content to the browser when it is available using the likes of node.js?

Answer (score -2):

I designed [my site](http://www.solarcoordinates.com/index.html) with AJAX exclusively, and it works perfectly except for one rather major issue:  Using AJAX requires JS to be enabled.  Of course, if users trust your site, this is not a problem, but if they don't, then an AJAX solution won't work unless you put the entire page in a noscript tag.

Comment: The page obviously doesn't gracefully degrade yet, but my approach was to build it assuming full functionality, and then work backwards from there.  It'll gracefully degrade eventually, but those who allow me to use JS are going to get first priority.  I also think that in order to degrade gracefully, it's important to know what you're degrading *from* in the first place.  It's also, in its current form, a great example of the problem of using the technique proposed by the OP with no fallback plan.